# iOS 5 and iOS 6 behavior for UITextField differs in case of KeyboardType Email

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, uitextfield

I have recently observed that you create 1 `UITextField` and set its **UIKeyboardType** to **Email** and set the property `setsecuretextentry` to **TRUE**.

Now note this behavior in iOS 5 and iOS 6 Device or Simulator...

Note that in iOS 5 Normal(Alphabet without @ sign) keyboard will open. And in iOS 6 Email type keyboard will open.

Has anyone else observed this behavior earlier?? Is there any bug already reported to Apple?? Can anyone explain how to tackle this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the iOS 6 behavior in iOS 5 too by doing setting the properties in code. Must be a bug in the way/order the properties are picked from the nib file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    self.textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fernando, i managed to get this.. But do you have any reference of such issue on Apple.

Comment: No, but if it was an issue, it was in iOS5, and has been fixed in iOS6, right? The iOS6 behavior is right and iOS5 is not.